# Why does higher temperature lead to lesser efficiency of photovoltaic cells?

Tags: energy, electronic-band-theory, solar-cells

I have understood that band gap decreases but why does that decrease lead to lower efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, increasing the temperature increases the number of charge carriers through thermal activation, which increases the recombination rate between minority and majority carriers, which eliminates the useful light-generated charge before it can be collected. Recombination suppresses both current collection and the open circuit voltage. See, for example, Green, "General Temperature
Dependence of Solar Cell Performance and Implications for Device Modelling," Dubey et al., "Temperature Dependent Photovoltaic (PV) Efficiency and Its Effect on PV Production in the World – A Review," and Singh and Ravindra, "Temperature dependence of solar cell performance—an analysis."